# How to obtain a JWT token via an AuthenticationProvider from an internal Oauth2 server without redirecting to the server for login

Tags: jwt, microservices, spring-oauth2

We have a microservice based environment running our own authentication server that will produce JWT tokens using the /oauth/token endpoint but this server does not provide a web login page.

For our front end application we have tried the oauth2Login setups but they all want to try and redirect the browser to the authentication server, authenticate and then redirect back to the application. Likewise oauth2Client setups add an AuthenticationProvider but that will only authenticate a OAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationToken but the user login request will generate a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken so oauth2Client provider never gets evaluated.

We were looking for something similar to the ldap authentication providers in that the username and password is collected locally and sent to the authorisation server. While we can write our own custom AuthencationProvider which accepts the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, communicates with the oauth server and return the generated JWT. We were hoping there was something pre-existing that was part of the current spring-boot framework. If our understanding is correct then the oauth2Client setup is what we are after but can't work out how to enable the initial authentication.

We are using spring boot 2.2.5.